# How to get a list of files from a folder

Tags: file, cmd, directory

I could really use some help. I have searched the topics here and on the web in general and got closer to what I need but not the whole way

I need a list of all the files and sub folders within a folder

I have found a lot of help in how to get the files and folders from a directory using Command Prompt, but in my case the directory is massive and would rather just specify the folder I need and then get the files that exist within that folder (and the sub folders and their files). Please also note I am not very technical and can just about manage basic queries with Command Prompt

I need:

A list that I can import into excel that contains - File name, File Path if possible, Amended Date, Author, File Type

The files I need all exist within subfolders in M:\Sales & Marketing\Sales\Sales Tools and some more that I need in M:\Sales & Marketing\Sales\Tenders\Tender Docs

I thought of copying them from the shared folder into my local directory but that was going to take over 2 hours to do

I really would appreciate any help that you can offer. I have tried changing all the examples along the lines of dir /s /b >> filelist.txt  to use the folder and path but no luck

Many many thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Foxidrive, thanks so much for the info you provided and it would have been wonderful. However I got an error message back in the file that was saying the execution of scrips is disabled. If there isnt another easy way of this I will see if the IT department can enable scripts

Answer (score 0):

Save all this into a batch file called say `MyInfo.bat` and then launch it.  In the same folder you should find `file.csv` with some info inside it that may help you.  It uses Powershell to get the information but can be launched as a batch file.

Where you mention `Author`, this returns the `owner` of the file.  The `file type` is shown by the extension in the filename.

```
@echo off
more +7 "%~f0" >"%temp%\a.ps1"
powershell "%temp%\a.ps1"  >"file.csv"
del "%temp%\a.ps1"
goto :EOF



$files = Get-ChildItem 'M:\Sales & Marketing\Sales\Sales Tools\*' -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files){
$acl = $file | get-acl | select path,owner
$result = "`"$($file.name.ToString())`",`"$($file.directoryname.ToString())`",`"$($acl.owner.ToString())`",$($file.lastwritetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))"
write-output $result
}

$files = Get-ChildItem 'M:\Sales & Marketing\Sales\Tenders\Tender Docs\*' -Recurse
foreach ($file in $files){
$acl = $file | get-acl | select path,owner
$result = "`"$($file.name.ToString())`",`"$($file.directoryname.ToString())`",`"$($acl.owner.ToString())`",$($file.lastwritetime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"))"
write-output $result
}
```

Comment: Hi Foxidrive, thanks so much for the info you provided and it would have been wonderful. However I got an error message back in the file that was saying the execution of scrips is disabled. If there isnt another easy way of this I will see if the IT department can enable scripts

Comment: Can you right click the batch file and run as admin?  Or is your account a limited user and you don't have admin passwords or access?

Comment: maybe you have to `Set-ExecutionPolicy`?